# Recursively Sum Matrix Until 0 in Column

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I want to recursively sum a matrix in Java. If the column encounters a 0, only sum the column portion above the zero. I've solved using a nested for loop, but I want to solve recursively to better understand recursion.

```
    static int solution(int[][] matrix) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
            sum += searchDown(matrix, 0, i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static int searchDown(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
        if (matrix[i][j] > 0) {
            searchDown(matrix, i + 1, j);
            return matrix[i][j];
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[][]{
                {0, 1, 1, 2},
                {0, 5, 0, 0},
                {2, 0, 3, 3}
        };
        int sum = solution(matrix);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

It only sums the top row. In the second row, I see 5 being returned in the call stack, but it's not be added to the sum for sum reason.

Comment: The method searchDown will return either null or the value of one cell. But the result of the recursive call is never used. That's where your addition is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a problem with the return.

```
static int searchDown(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
    if (matrix[i][j] > 0) {
        return matrix[i][j] + searchDown(matrix, i + 1, j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

besides... I would suggest you add a checking condition if i or j would be out of bound.

Get this in your mind. Recursion doesn't stop until you tell it to. I would get more conditioning statements to prevent the program from behaving in ways you don't expect it to.